# Install vim plugins without internet in windows

Tags: windows, vim

I have installed vim in windows. But I can't install vim plugins. I tried putting files in vim folder. But it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

To install a plugin, we need to know what form it comes in and vim directory structure. It can be:

```
STANDARD STRUCTURE           

~/.vim/autoload/...          
      /doc/...               
      /ftplugin/...          
      /indent/...            
      /plugin/...            
      /syntax/...            
      /...
```

**Plugin types :**

- A single `.vim` file : This supposed to be placed in the `.vim/plugin` directory.
- a Vimball file : Simply open the vimball file in Vim and then execute :source %. You can delete vimball file after you have sourced it.
- A set of files in directories that follow an expected structure (`plugin/*`, `syntax/*`, etc.) : A set of files in the standard directory layout can be installed either by copying them to `.vim`, or using a [plugin package manager](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/388/what-is-the-difference-between-the-vim-package-managers).

Plugins may depends which OS you're on, especially if the plugin calls in external commands. For most plugins, though, it may not matter.

**Reference :**

- [Install a plugin in vim](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/613/how-do-i-install-a-plugin-in-vim-vi/614#614)